# how to hide div in first page, from another page?

Tags: jquery, html

i have some normal div on my first page:

```
<div id="news">
            <div class="loginform">

                <div id="form_news">

                <form id="loginform" method="post" action="envianews.asp">
                <div id="news_campos">
                    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" value="" title="Nome" placeholder="NOME" autocomplete="off" required />
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" title="Email" placeholder="EMAIL" autocomplete="off" required/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="bt_news" name="submit" id="submit" value=""/>
                <div id="news_response"></div>
                </form>             

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

and on my `envianews.asp` i have the script to send these information to de database. i Want to know what i need to do, for when the person click on the button for send the data, hide my div `news`...

Comment: But submitting to `envianews.asp` will refresh the whole page, so why would you only want to hide the '#news' div?

Comment: yes.. i want only to hide these `#news` div on my `index.html` page.. for example..

Comment: So you don't want the whole page to refresh, is that right?

Comment: yes... because i have these "newslettert" system in many pages of site...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
 $("#submit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post("envianews.asp", { name: $("#nome").val(), email: $("#email").val() } ,function(data){
     $("#news_campos").hide();  // hide when we get the resonse from ajax call
  });

 });
});
```

Comment: i like your example... but i have some question: what i put in place of `{data: "yourdata"}` ? my input values??

Comment: @Preston: Yes your form element values.

Comment: this way?: `{data: "nome","email"}` (these are the name of my form elements) sorry but i dont understand very well..

Comment: @Preston: You should read the value of your input elements and send that. I updated my answer to send your input elements.

Comment: thankz for help.. i'm waiting the staff of the hosting to set the record permission on my database to test your example...

Answer (score 1):

use http://jquery.com/

and then to hide div use

```
$("#news").hide();
```

And for sending values to Database use Ajax

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Comment: Nobody would see this since the page will be replaced by envianews.asp

Comment: probably he wants to hide it till the request is submitted

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, after you send your data and you want to hide your div all you have to do is:

```
document.getElementById('news').style.display = 'none'
```

Comment: Nobody would see this since the page will be replaced by envianews.asp

Comment: on my envianews.asp i have only the script for record on database, so in the end of these page i input this: 

`<script language="javascript">
 document.getElementById('news').style.display = 'none'
</script>` thats right??

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#news').hide();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TRWkK/)